# how do I add preprocessor #define in devenv command line?

Tags: preprocessor, devenv

Is there a way to add extra preprocessor #define in devenv command line?

Comment: no, that's invalid syntax - it shows devenv help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you mean by vcbuild command line but if you mean the Visual C++ command line compiler then you can add defines by add /Dxxxx, e.g.

```
cl.exe /DSHAREWARE ....
```

Additional answer based on comments:

You should be able to set the CL environment variable with the extra preprocessor define:

```
SET CL=/DSHAREWARE
devenv ....
```

Mere information can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kezkeayy.aspx)

Comment: I had in mind devenv.exe. cl only compiles IIRC. devenv does linking as well.

Comment: That works fine - I just found the same answer somewhere else. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Well, then you should accept the answer so others can see that this question is solved...

Answer (score 3):

in your project settings, add the following preprocessor definition:

$(MyPreprocessorDefinitions);

then in your *.bat file, use

REM #define MY_DEF

set MyPreprocessorDefinitions=MY_DEF

devenv.exe ...

REM #undefine MY_DEF

set MyPreprocessorDefinitions=

Answer (score 2):

The #defines are defined in your Visual Studio project file (.dsp or .vcproj file).  This is a simple text file.  So you could edit the project file from a script, then call devenv.exe.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to use devenv for other reasons, (and was running in cygwin, so i had sed).

I set a Compilation symbol in the project's properties `SED_REPLACE_THIS`
and then used sed to set it to something meaningful (ie: `DONT_CRASH_AS_MUCH`)

`sed -i 's/SED_REPLACE_THIS/DONT_CRASH_AS_MUCH/g' project.csproj`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way without modifying solution or project files so I came up with the following:

- Create empty file as part of build e.g. `feature_flag.h`
- Replace `#if FEATURE_FLAG` with `#if !__has_include("feature_flag.h")`
- Remove `feature_flag.h` at the end of the build

It's not using #define but it does use the preprocessor which was what I needed.