# devenv and #define

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, command-line, c-preprocessor, devenv

I'm building some projects using cmd devenv.

For some projects I want to #define form the command line.

Is there a way to #define using the cmd and devenv? I don't want to create new configurations.

Comment: A "better" answer can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783158/how-do-i-add-preprocessor-define-in-devenv-command-line ... you can set an environment variable CL with whatever extra command line options you want cl.exe to use during the build process, such as this:

set CL=/DSOMETHING=1

Answer (score 6):

You could do this:

- Add `$(AdditionalPreprocessorDefinitions)` to the list of preprocessor definitions of the project. After that, they might look like `WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;$(AdditionalPreprocessorDefinitions);%(PreprocessorDefinitions)`
- Use `msbuild` instead of `devenv` to start the build process
- Specify the additional preprocessor definitions by adding `/p:AdditionalPreprocessorDefinitions="SOMEDEF;ANOTHERDEF"` to the command line.

Please not that I picked the name *AdditionalPreprocessorDefinitions* just for clarity, you can pick something shorter. This will only work with VC2010, because in earlier versions, VC++ projects were not built with msbuild.

Comment: I tried using the msbuild using /p:Definition="TEST" but it didn't work 
it tried /p:DefineConstants="TEST" didn't work neither
What i'm doing wrong?
I'm compiling a solution with 3 projects

Comment: Did you follow step 1 of the list above? The DefineConstants thing is C# only, in this solution for C++ you have to edit the project and insert $(VariableName); into the preprocessor definitions string.

Comment: Yes I tried adding the $(Flavors) to the preprocessor definitions 
now it looks:WIN32;NDEBUG;_WINDOWS;%(Flavors);%(PreprocessorDefinitions)
and I use the command msbuild project.sln /p:Flavors="Test" /t:rebuild
It's still not working

Comment: @alejo try replacing %(Flavors) with $(Flavors)

Comment: now it's working fine, 
That was a really bad mistake,
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Many compilers allow you to set define macros at the command line.  The common option is "-D".

Check your compiler documentation for exact syntax.

Edit 1:
The Visual Studio compiler has configuration options to specify the macros in the IDE (which get passed to the compiler using the "-D" switch.)

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this with devenv.exe, see the [Command Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx).  You can do this with the compiler however, cl.exe but then you can't reuse all the settings in your project file.

Comment: I tried using the msbuild using /p:Definition="TEST" but it didn't work 
it tried /p:DefineConstants="TEST" didn't work neither
What i'm doing wrong?
I'm compiling a solution with 3 projects